# Algorithm for Regular Language

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, regular-language

Let $L$ be a regular language with the alphabet $\Sigma$. I'm trying to find an algorithm to tell whether $L=\Sigma^{*}$, whether $L$ accepts all strings in its alphabet. I think this algorithm uses converting the language to a DFA, but I'm not sure what to do from there.
[image: question source]

Comment: How is given your language $L$?

Comment: The book I'm using is using $L$ as a stand in for some arbitrary regular language

Comment: This does not answer my question, I am afraid... If you want an algorithm, you need to specify how your input is given...

Comment: I've edited the question to include the source, in case I didn't capture the full question. For inputs, in general the book has had us use 0 and 1 as inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that $L$ is represented by a DFA. (If not, begin by converting the regular expression or regular grammar representing it to a DFA; this can be done algorithmically.) There are several possibilities, among them the following:

1. Apply one of the algorithms that reduce a DFA to a minimal DFA, and check to see whether it has exactly one state, and that state is an acceptor state.
2. Apply an algorithm that removes all inaccessible states from the DFA, and check that the remaining states are all acceptor states.
3. Let $p$ be the number of states in the DFA, and test whether every word of length less than $p$.

I’ll leave it to you to show that these actually work.